# Mount subfolder from NTFS drive via entry in /etc/fstab

Tags: fstab, ntfs, automount

I have a NTFS hard drive connected to my Raspberry Pi.
The structure of the drive is:

```
F:\
- Images
- Other
- Movie
```

I would like to mount only the F:\Movie folder in /mnt/disk/Movie in read-only.

My fstab looks like:

```
UUID=(lots of letters and numbers) Movie /mnt/disk/Movie   ntfs   defaults,uid=0,gid=0,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,noatime,nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=2
```

but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome. What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Do you consider it an issue if the whole partition is mounted? If not, then just remove `Movie` from the `fstab` entry, and the `Movie` directory will mount at `/mnt/disk/Film/Movie`. If you want it mounted elsewhere, change `/mnt/disk/Film` appropriately and/or use a bind mount. In all cases, `Images` and `Other` will also be mounted. If that is your issue, I think you'll have to use some trickery to hide them.

Comment: Yes, because I would like to mount one subfolder (/mnt/disk/Movie) in read-only mode and another one (/mnt/disk/Images) in rw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to mount only one subfolder of a complete partition - also in Windows you cannot just set a drive letter for only one folder in the Disk Managment.

You will have to mount the whole partition - you can do this read-only. Then you can access all three folders. If you want to have some software not be directly aware of the other folders, you could create a soft-link to that specific folder.

First remove the folder name ("Movie") from the fstab entry and while unmounted, create a folder /mnt/disk/Film. When you mount the partition, all folders will be contained in /mnt/disk/Film.

If you want to have the "Movie" folder in /media/Film, then you first ensure that the folder /media exists. Then execute `ln -s /mnt/disk/Film/Movie /media/Film` and you can access /media/Film to get the contents of F:\Movie.

The soft link will even continue to exist if the partition is unmounted, but will then point to the empty mount folder. This could lead to the situation where a mount hides files that were written during the unmounted phase - you can reveal them again by unmounting.

Comment: Ok, if mounting only one subfolder is not possible then I'll explain better my need. I would like to have one subfolder (/mnt/disk/Movie) in read-only mode and another one (/mnt/disk/Images) in rw (the "Other" folder can be in whatever mode). Is that possible? The problem here is that I cannot change the permissions with chmod because the filesystem is NTFS.